# What does "rather" mean in "rather Jimmy Olsen-ish"?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

*Jimmy Olsenish* means "similar to Jimmy Olsen":

> He is a nice enough boy - **rather Jimmy Olsen-ish** I thought.
>
> She has an unreal figure, **rather Barbie-ish** in its proportions!

When you say, for instance, he is similar to Jimmy Olsen (in appearance, behaviour and character) you would say ***Jimmy Olsen-ish***.

However, I can not understand the grammar points and meaning of the word ***rather*** here.  Could you explain in detail?

Comment: I think choster answered that question (which you asked in comment) already. http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19403/use-of-the-suffix-ish#comment35952_19420. I also suggested dictionaries for the meaning of "rather". Have you looked it up yet?

Comment: @Damkerng Just now saw your link. My answer is a duplicate. It was already answered in your link.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the word "childish". When we say it's a childish behavior we mean that it's a childlike behavior or the behavior is similar to a child. So in both the following sentences you are right about the meaning of Name + "-ish" construction

> He is a nice enough boy - rather Jimmy Olsen-ish I thought. (Olsen-ish = Olsen like or similar to Olsen)
>
> She has an unreal figure, rather Barbie-ish in its proportions! (Barbie like or similar to Barbie)

Here is a usage note from dictionary -

> **-ish**
>
> 1. (a suffix) used to form adjectives from nouns, with the sense of “belonging to” ( British; Danish; English; Spanish  ); “after the
>      manner of,” “having the characteristics of,” “like” ( babyish;
>      girlish; mulish  ); “addicted to,” “inclined or tending to” ( bookish;
>      freakish  ); “near or about” ( fiftyish; sevenish  ).
> 2. (a suffix) used to form adjectives from other adjectives, with the sense of “somewhat,” “rather” ( oldish; reddish; sweetish  ).

Now come to the usage of "rather" in this context -

**Rather -** *[AS SUBMODIFIER] To a certain or significant extent or degree:*

**Example -**

> 1. She’s been behaving rather strangely.
> 2. He’s rather an unpleasant man.

Now I am going to write the meaning of your sentences -

> He is a nice enough boy - rather Jimmy Olsen-ish I thought. = *He is a nice enough boy - almost like Olsen.*
>
> She has an unreal figure, rather Barbie-ish in its proportions! = *She has an unreal figure, almost like Barbie in its proportions!*

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Rather has the same meaning as 'quite' or 'somewhat' in this context.

Comment: When has the word RATHER a negative meaning?

Comment: The use of the 'rather' is unrelated to the negativity of the statement. :)

Answer (score -1):

[The following quote about *rather* is from WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=rather&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=):

> • on the contrary; "rather than disappoint the children, he did two quick tricks before he left"; "he didnt call; rather (or instead), he wrote her a letter"; "used English terms instead of Latin ones"
>
> • to some (great or small) extent; "it was rather cold"; "the party was rather nice"; "the knife is rather dull"; "I rather regret that I cannot attend"; "Hes rather good at playing the cello"; "he is kind of shy"
>
> • more readily or willingly; "clean it well, preferably with warm water"; "Id rather be in Philadelphia"; "Id sooner die than give up"
>
> • to a degree (not used with a negative) "quite tasty"; "quite soon"; "quite ill"; "quite rich"

Comment: Please, if you're going to quote something, remember to make it clear that it's a quote and give credit to the original source.